# How to make a cumsum each 3 values of a vector in R

Tags: r, matlab, sum, cumsum

Im trying to make a accumulated summatory of any vector and get the accumulation each 3 values, for example:

```
a: 1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
   8
   9
   10
```

`b` = Accumulated sum of the values each 3 values

```
b =  3
     6
     9
    12
    15
    18
    21
    24
    27
    19
```

In Matlab it is easily solved with `b=movsum(a,3)`. What is the easiest way to do it in R?

Comment: `zoo::rollapply(1:10, 3, sum, partial = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 1:10
sapply(seq_along(a), function(i) sum(a[max(1, i-1):min(length(a), i+1)]))
# [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 19
```

You could write you own function

```
movsum = function(x, n){
    before = floor(n - n/2)
    after = n - before - 1
    sapply(seq_along(x), function(i)
        sum(x[max(1, i-before):min(length(a), i+after)]))
}
movsum(1:10, 3)
# [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 19
```

NOTE that if `n` is even, the function will take fewer elements on the right

Answer (score 1):

The `zoo` package has a `rollapply` function that allows you to iterate over a moving window of arbitrary width, which means you can do

```
zoo::rollapply(1:10, 3, sum, partial = TRUE)
#> [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 19
```

Answer (score 1):

`rollsum` can be useful.

```
zoo::rollsum(x, 3)
[1]  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27
```